# Error importing Spring Context Annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

When I import a Controller annotation on Spring, the following error occours:

```
The import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller conflicts with a type defined in the same file
```

Here goes the (very simple) code of my starting web-MVC project:

```
package com.company.project.servlet;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class Controller {

    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("Controller executing...");
        return("page");
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is aparently no reason to an error be shown here. Have you any idea on what should be happening? Thanks!

Usefull information:
- Eclipse Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0 (over Kepler)
- Eclipse jars version 4.0.0.M1
(It should be the lattest versions of all these stuff)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The message says it all :

> The import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller conflicts with a type defined in the same file

You have defined a single type in your file: the class `Controller`, which conflicts with the annotation `Controller`.

```
@Controller ---> same name
                     ^
                     |
public class Controller {
```

Choose another name, or use the fully qualified name of the enum:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller 
public class Controller {
```

Comment: Good one! excellent... I'm new to annotations and I didn't know that annotations interact with other ellements of the code, like reserved words... thanks a lot!

Comment: Annotations are classes. And you can't import two classes with the same name, or use a class which has the same name as the class you're defining. You would have the same problem if you defined another regular class named Controller in another package and tried to import it.

Answer (score 2):

`@Controller` is a keyword, so choose another class name.